# TestCafe loop through DOM

Tags: dom, automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm having some trouble with accessing the `DOM` node of the `nth` items accessed from `Selector` in `testCafe`:

```
var element = Selector('input');
console.log(element) //logs a function - too early
var elementTest = await element();
console.log(elementTest) // logs first DOM node
var elementsCount = await element.count; // logs 5
console.log(`Elements: ${elementsCount}`);
for(let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
    const test =  await element.nth(i);
    console.log(`${i}: ${ test }`); // logs a function - too early
    const sanity = await test(); // breaks the loop
}`
```

Answer (score 4):

It is strange, it should work.
Try this solution:

```
const elements = Selector('input');
var elementsCount = await elements.count;
for(let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
    const elementSelector = elements.nth(i);
    const sanity = await elementSelector();
}
```